# Git suddenly stopped working ( passwd file)

Tags: git, clone, pull

I was working on server and doing few git pull. It worked fine. Suddenly I get this message:
`fatal: unable to look up current user in the passwd file`

Tried to do git clone on another dir, the same issue. Git's working fine on other server and on localhost.

Any ideas what could happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271926/git-error-unable-to-look-up-current-user-in-the-passwd-file-no-such-user-wh

does this answer your question?

Comment: also i guess this fixes your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121295/4903754

Comment: but I don't store user/password anywhere, I write them when prompt always

Comment: This is a system error on your server (presumably a Unix or Linux machine); the `whoami` and `id` commands may also fail. It needs to be addressed by the system operator. Git, however, can work around the problem, using the question and answer suggested by @Isitar. (It doesn't matter where you type in passwords as this is a system error.)

Comment: @Isitar again, the same issue, it's somehow connected to crons. And last time fixed itself after few hours. Setting git config does not help. Any ideas?
*note - this is not VPS, but shared hosting so I cannot simply restart server which I would normally do